# How can I upload a file to vue public folder?

Tags: axios, upload, frontend, vuejs3, fetch-api

I'm able to get file from public folder, used fetch and axios a to get a json file from public folder and both worked fine but when i tried to post it gives Error 404,  I dont have a backend its just a front end project. I need to upload a .json file to vue public folder and the render data using chart.js. I used the same on code somewhere else and it worked.

**Here's the code**

```
axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
     JSON.stringify({ title: 'Vue POST Request Example' }))
     .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
})
```

its giving an OK response

and when i change this with 'localhost:8080/' or '../' it gives 404 error or when with ip:8080 then cross origin request blocked error.

**Here's the code that's giving error**

```
 axios.post('https://localhost:8080/',
     JSON.stringify({ title: 'Vue POST Request Example' }))
     .then(response => {
       console.log(response);
  })
```

Every tutorial I watched had a backend where they upload so do i need to add backend or is it doable.